# How to get bias and neuron weights in optimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In a TensorFlow optimizer (python) the method `apply_dense` does get called for the neuron weights (layer connections) and the bias weights but I would like to use both in this method.

```
def _apply_dense(self, grad, weight):
    ...
```

For example: A fully connected neural network with two hidden layer with two neurons and a bias for each.

[image: Neural network example]

If we take a look at layer 2 we get in `apply_dense` a call for the neuron weights:

[image: neuron weights]

and a call for the bias weights:

[image: bias weights]

But I would either need both matrix in one call of `apply_dense` or a weight matrix like this:

[image: all weights from one layer]

*X_2X_4, B_1X_4, ... is just a notation for the weight of the connection between the two neurons. Therefore B_1X_4 ist only a placeholder for the weight between B_1 and X_4.*

How to do this?

**MWE**

For an minimal working example here a stochastic gradient descent optimizer implementation with a momentum. For every layer the momentum of all incoming connections from other neurons is reduced to the mean (see ndims == 2). What i need instead is the mean of not only the momentum values from the incoming neuron connections but also from the incoming bias connections (as described above).

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training import optimizer


class SGDmomentum(optimizer.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, mu=0.9, use_locking=False, name="SGDmomentum"):
        super(SGDmomentum, self).__init__(use_locking, name)
        self._lr = learning_rate
        self._mu = mu

        self._lr_t = None
        self._mu_t = None

    def _create_slots(self, var_list):
        for v in var_list:
            self._zeros_slot(v, "a", self._name)

    def _apply_dense(self, grad, weight):
        learning_rate_t = tf.cast(self._lr_t, weight.dtype.base_dtype)
        mu_t = tf.cast(self._mu_t, weight.dtype.base_dtype)
        momentum = self.get_slot(weight, "a")

        if momentum.get_shape().ndims == 2:  # neuron weights
            momentum_mean = tf.reduce_mean(momentum, axis=1, keep_dims=True)
        elif momentum.get_shape().ndims == 1:  # bias weights
            momentum_mean = momentum
        else:
            momentum_mean = momentum

        momentum_update = grad + (mu_t * momentum_mean)
        momentum_t = tf.assign(momentum, momentum_update, use_locking=self._use_locking)

        weight_update = learning_rate_t * momentum_t
        weight_t = tf.assign_sub(weight, weight_update, use_locking=self._use_locking)

        return tf.group(*[weight_t, momentum_t])

    def _prepare(self):
        self._lr_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(self._lr, name="learning_rate")
        self._mu_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(self._mu, name="momentum_term")
```

For a simple neural network: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py (only change the optimizer to the custom SGDmomentum optimizer)

Comment: You need to be more explicit. What method are you calling? Can you give us a minimal working example?

Comment: I'm implementing an optimizer. I have added a MWE of such an optimizer and a description of what the requirement is in terms of my question.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to get the weights in your network?

Comment: @RyanStout: No. I'm writing an optimizer and want to access neuron and bias weights in the optimizer's apply_dense method at the same time.

Comment: Are you saying that _apply_dense gets called twice, once with the weight matrix passed into the parameter called "weight" and once with the bias vector passed into the parameter called "weight"? I think I'm also not following why you have weights=[[B_1*X_4],[B_2*X_5]] in the question.

Comment: Yes. I think it's normal that for every network that has bias weights apply_dense is getting called for each. There is no '*' between B_1X_4. That was just a notation for connections between the neurons of the neuronal network at the beginning of my question. So B_1X_4 only is a placeholder for the weight of the connection between the bias B_1 and the neuron X_4.

Answer (score 1):

*Update*: I'll try to give a better answer (or at least some ideas) now that I have some understanding of your goal, but, as you suggest in the comments, there is probably not infallible way of doing this in TensorFlow.

Since TF is a general computation framework, there is no good way of determining what pairs of weights and biases are there in a model (or if it is a neural network at all). Here are some possible approaches to the problem that I can think of:

- Annotating the tensors. This is probably not practical since you already said you have no control over the model, but an easy option would be to add extra attributes to the tensors to signify the weight/bias relationships. For example, you could do something like `W.bias = B` and `B.weight = W`, and then in `_apply_dense` check `hasattr(weight, "bias")` and `hasattr(weight, "weight")` (there may be some better designs in this sense).
- You can look into some framework built on top of TensorFlow where you may have better information about the model structure. For example, [Keras](https://keras.io/) is a layer-based framework that implements its own [optimizer classes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py) (based on TensorFlow or Theano). I'm not too familiar with the code or its extensibility, but probably you have more tools there to use.
- Detect the structure of the network yourself from the optimizer. This is quite complicated, but theoretically possible. from the loss tensor passed to the optimizer, it should be possible to "climb up" in the model graph to reach all of its nodes (taking the `.op` of the tensors and the `.inputs` of the ops). You could detect tensor multiplications and additions with variables and skip everything else (activations, loss computation, etc) to determine the structure of the network; if the model does not match your expectations (e.g. there are no multiplications or there is a multiplication without a later addition) you can raise an exception indicating that your optimizer cannot be used for that model.

---

***Old answer, kept for the sake of keeping.***

*I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, so I'm not sure if this really answers your question.*

Let's say you have a dense layer transforming an input of size *M* to an output of size *N*. According to the convention you show, you'd have an *N* × *M* weights matrix *W* and a *N*-sized bias vector *B*. Then, an input vector *X* of size *M* (or a batch of inputs of size *M* × *K*) would be processed by the layer as *W* · *X* + *B*, and then applying the activation function (in the case of a batch, the addition would be a "broadcasted" operation). In TensorFlow:

```
X = ...  # Input batch of size M x K
W = ...  # Weights of size N x M
B = ...  # Biases of size N

Y = tf.matmul(W, X) + B[:, tf.newaxis]  # Output of size N x K
# Activation...
```

If you want, you can always put *W* and *B* together in a single extended weights matrix *W**, basically adding *B* as a new row in *W*, so *W** would be (*N* + 1) × *M*. Then you just need to add a new element to the input vector *X* containing a constant 1 (or a new row if it's a batch), so you would get *X** with size *N* + 1 (or (*N* + 1) × *K* for a batch). The product *W** · *X** would then give you the same result as before. In TensorFlow:

```
X = ...  # Input batch of size M x K
W_star = ...  # Extended weights of size (N + 1) x M
# You can still have a "view" of the original W and B if you need it
W = W_star[:N]
B = W_star[-1]

X_star = tf.concat([X, tf.ones_like(X[:1])], axis=0)
Y = tf.matmul(W_star, X_star)  # Output of size N x K
# Activation...
```

Now you can compute gradients and updates for weights and biases together. A drawback of this approach is that if you want to apply regularization then you should be careful to apply it only on the weights part of the matrix, not on the biases.

Comment: Thank you for trying to come up with an answer to my question. Sadly you are right and this isn't an actual answer to my question. The problem that I try to solve is that from a optimizer point of view I can't control how the network looks like. So given Y = tf.matmul(W, X) + B I still want to use W and B in one call of apply_dense. A answer to my question can only come from a optimizer point of view and not from outside like your answer. The restriction is that I can only change the optimizer not the network.

Comment: @Spen Okay, I've taken a look at the base optimizer class and I see the kind of stuff you want to do now. But I still don't understand, if you can't control what the model looks like, how can you guarantee that there will actually be biases? Or that the model is a neural network at all? In TF, the biases and the wieghts will be just two independent variable objects, if you can't control the model I'm not sure how you'd know which are the pairs of weights and biases.

Comment: Yes, I see this problem too. I did just think it is a given that the corresponding weights and biases are coming after each other and that the weight matrix has a dimension of 2 and the bias matrix a dimension of 1. But maybe you are right and there isn't a save way to do this in tensorflow. In other frameworks this is possible since you have access to the full network but in tensorflow this access doesn't seem to be possible. Since the bounty is running out and you were the only one trying to help I will award it to you.

Comment: @Spen That's really kind of you, thank you :) I've updated the answer with some better suggestions, although, like you say, there is probably no straightforward solution.